# Derive the probability mass function and the CDF of $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A coin is being thrown until heads and tails both have appeared at least twice. Let $X$ be the number of times the coin is thrown until the game ends. Derive the probability mass function and the CDF of $X$. Find the smallest $n$ for which $P(X \le n) > \frac{9}{10}$.

I have hard time figuring out the probability mass function for this scenario. According to wikipedia the probability mass function is defined by $$p_X(x)=P(X=x)$$ for $-\infty<x< \infty$. I ought to think that I wouldn't need to compute all the values from the range $(-\infty, \infty)$ in order to find $p_X$... If $X$ is the number of times the coin is thrown until the game ends then how do I start looking at $P(X=1)$ etc to figure this out?

Comment: Hint: for $n\ge4$, determine the number of $n$-toss sequences that obtain $X>n$, then use $P(X=n+1)=P(X>n)-P(X>n+1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the probability mass function may be found easily enough.

You cannot finish the game prior to the fourth toss.

For any $n\geq 4$, the event of $X=n$ is the event of tossing either $1$ tail among the first $n-1$ tosses and a second tail on the next, *or* $1$ head among the first $n-1$ tosses and a second head on the next.$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=n)~&=~2~\binom{n-1}1 \left(\dfrac 12\right)^{n}\,\mathbf 1_{n\in\Bbb [[4..\infty)]}\\&=2^{1-n}(n-1)\,\mathbf 1_{n\in[[4..\infty)]}\end{align}$$

---

You may find the cummulative distribution function similarly, by looking at the survival function.

$\mathsf P(X\leq n)=1-\mathsf P(X>n)$.

$X$ is certainly greater than $3$.

For any integer $n\geq 4$, the event of $X\gt n$ requires us to have thrown, among the first $n$ tosses, *neither* more than one head *nor* more than one tail.

What is the probability of this?